# Right-shifting a numpy array changes dtype?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I create an int32 array:

```py
a = np.array([3], dtype=np.int32)

np.issubdtype(a.dtype, np.int32)
Out[2]: True
```

but if I shift it, it's no longer an int32 subtype:

```py
b = a >> 1

np.issubdtype(b.dtype, np.int32)
Out[4]: False
```

Yet it actually is?

```
b.dtype
Out[5]: dtype('int32')

b.dtype == np.int32
Out[6]: True
```

If I compare the attributes:

```py
for attr in dir(a.dtype):
    if not attr.startswith("__"):
        print(f'{attr} =', a.dtype.__getattribute__(attr))
```

They both have type string `<i4` and base `int32`. These are the only ones that differ:

a:

```
char = l
num = 7
type = <class 'numpy.int32'>
```

b:

```
char = i
num = 5
type = <class 'numpy.intc'>
```

Why does right-shifting change the type?

Why is it no longer a subdtype of np.int32, even though the dtype is equal to np.int32?

That's on Windows, but on Linux the output is the same?

```py
a.dtype.type
Out[9]: numpy.int32

b.dtype.type
Out[10]: numpy.int32

a.dtype is b.dtype
Out[11]: True
```

Comment: NumPy's C-level dtype handling is based on C `char/short/int/long/long long` rather than `int8_t/int16_t/int32_t/int64_t`, so it produces a few weird "evil twin" dtypes that aren't usually exposed.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica The associated question has nothing to do with this question

Comment: It's the same evil-twin-dtype-after-math issue, just looking at a different difference between the evil twin and the regular dtype.

Comment: In version 1.19dev, the dtypes don't change.  `Out[4]` is True.  I don't know if recent version(s) have cleaned up the dtype handling that @user2357112supportsMonica refers to.

Comment: @hpaulj: Are you testing on Windows or something else? The behavior is OS-dependent, since C `long` is 32-bit on Windows.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm using 1.18.1 on Windows

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ok but it doesn't answer my questions